# Xtext field dot-notation scope provider

Tags: xtext

Can the "memory" be avoided in the following Xtext scope provider for the field dot-notation of the following grammar, which is stock-standard except for the field dot-notation of the LocalRelation.

```
grammar test.path.Path with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate path "http://www.path.test/Path"

Model:
    (elements+=AbstractElement)*;

PackageDeclaration:
    'package' name=QualifiedName '{'
    (elements+=AbstractElement)*
    '}';

AbstractElement:
    PackageDeclaration | Entity | Import;

Import:
    'import' importedNamespace=QualifiedNameWithWildcard;

Entity:
    'entity' name=ID '{'
    relations+=Relation*
    '}';

Relation:
    GlobalRelation | LocalRelation;

GlobalRelation:
    ('id')? name=ID ':' ('*' | '+' | '?')? ref=[Entity|QualifiedName];


LocalRelation:
    ('id')? name=ID ':' ('*' | '+' | '?')? 'this' '.' head=[Relation|ID] ('.' tail+=[Relation|ID])*;


QualifiedNameWithWildcard:
    QualifiedName '.*'?;

QualifiedName:
    ID ('.' ID)*;
```

The follow grammar instance demonstrates the LocalRelation dot-notion.

```
entity A {
    b : B 
}

entity B {
    a : A 
}    

entity C { 
    b : B 
    x1 : this.b  
    x2 : this.x1 
//  x3 : this.x3  No self ref
    x4 : this.b.a     
    x5 : this.x1.a 
    x6 : this.x1.a.b.a.b.a.b.a
}          

entity D { 
    c : C
    x1 : this.c.b.a 
}
```

The scoping resolution for GlobalRelations works out of the box, but of course the scoping for LocalRelations does not. I have come up with the following working scope provider, but it uses a global map to keep track of dot-depth, together with a special head to set the counter to zero, since one cannot sample the value of a reference before it is defined as that causes an infinite loop.

```
class PathScopeProvider extends AbstractPathScopeProvider {

    @Inject extension IQualifiedNameProvider


    override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
        if (context instanceof LocalRelation) {
            return if (reference == PathPackage.Literals.LOCAL_RELATION__HEAD)
                getScopeLocalRelation_HEAD(context as LocalRelation, context.eContainer as Entity)
            else if (reference == PathPackage.Literals.LOCAL_RELATION__TAIL)
                getScopeLocalRelation_TAIL(context as LocalRelation, context.eContainer as Entity)
        }
        return super.getScope(context, reference);
    }

    def IScope getScopeLocalRelation_HEAD(LocalRelation contextLocalRelation,
        Entity contextLocalRelationContainingEntity) {
        // Don't touch contextLocalRelation.head not contextLocalRelation.tail!
        val result = newArrayList
        contextLocalRelationContainingEntity.relations.filter(
            target |
                target != contextLocalRelation
        ).forEach [ target |
            {
                result.add(EObjectDescription.create(QualifiedName.create(target.name), target))
                resetDepth(contextLocalRelation)
            }
        ]
        return new SimpleScope(IScope.NULLSCOPE, result)
    }

    def IScope getScopeLocalRelation_TAIL(LocalRelation contextLocalRelation,
        Entity contextLocalRelationContainingEntity) {
        // Note that head is well-defined, while tail is well-defined up to depth
        val head = contextLocalRelation.head
        val result = newArrayList
        val depthSoFar = getDepth(contextLocalRelation)
        incDepth(contextLocalRelation)
        val targetSoFar = if(depthSoFar === 0) head else contextLocalRelation.tail.get(depthSoFar - 1)
        if (targetSoFar instanceof GlobalRelation) {
            val targetSoFar_Global = targetSoFar as GlobalRelation
            targetSoFar_Global.ref.relations.forEach [ t |
                result.add(EObjectDescription.create(QualifiedName.create(t.name), t))
            ]
        } else if (targetSoFar instanceof LocalRelation) {
            var Relation i = targetSoFar as LocalRelation
            while (i instanceof LocalRelation) {
                i = if(i.tail.empty) i.head else i.tail.last
            }
            (i as GlobalRelation).ref.relations.forEach [ t |
                result.add(EObjectDescription.create(QualifiedName.create(t.name), t))
            ]
        }
        return new SimpleScope(IScope.NULLSCOPE, result)
    }

    // DEPTH MEMORY
    val enity_relation__depthSoFar = new HashMap<String, Integer>()

    private def void resetDepth(LocalRelation r) {
        enity_relation__depthSoFar.put(r.fullyQualifiedName.toString, 0)
    }

    private def int getDepth(LocalRelation r) {
        enity_relation__depthSoFar.get(r.fullyQualifiedName.toString)
    }

    private def int incDepth(LocalRelation r) {
        enity_relation__depthSoFar.put(r.fullyQualifiedName.toString, getDepth(r) + 1)
    }

}
```

- Can this additional depth memory be avoided in any way?
- Is there some internal way of detecting the depth of the tail so far scoped?

I have experimented with a try-catch block but that doesn't work, and would be sloppy anyway.

Comment: did you have a look at a recursive grammar instead of an iterative?
https://www.dietrich-it.de/xtext/2013/05/18/xtext-and-dot-expressions.html
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1722095/?srch=xtext+DotExpression+getScope#msg_1722095 (pseudo code for new scope provider)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. A googled a lot in producing this solution, and never found your above reference. I wish I had. Will study it.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is derived from [Xtext and Dot/Path-Expressions](https://www.dietrich-it.de/xtext/2013/05/18/xtext-and-dot-expressions.html), as suggested by  Christian Dietrich, and that is the example to use if you are looking to implement standard *field dot path* scoping.

The grammar above requires a small change.

```
LocalRelation:
    ('id')? name=ID ':' ('*' | '+' | '?')? 'this' '.' path=Path;

Path: head=[Relation|ID] ({Path.curr=current}  "." tail+=[Relation|ID])*;
```

The only change is `{Path.curr=current}` and this is the "magic ingredient" that makes all the difference. The scope provider is now almost trivial, especially compared to the monster in the OP.

```
override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
    if (context instanceof Path) {
        if (reference == PathPackage.Literals.PATH__HEAD) {
            // Filter self reference
            return new FilteringScope(super.getScope(context, reference), [ e |
                !Objects.equals(e.getEObjectOrProxy(), context)
            ]);
        } else  { // DOT_EXPRESSION__TAIL 
            val target = context.curr.followTheDots
            if (target === null) {
                return IScope::NULLSCOPE
            }
            return new FilteringScope(super.getScope(target, reference), [ e |
                !Objects.equals(e.getEObjectOrProxy(), context)
            ]);
        }
    }
    return super.getScope(context, reference);
}

def Entity followTheDots(Path path) {
    var targetRelation = if(path.tail === null || path.tail.empty) path.head else path.tail.last;
    return if (targetRelation instanceof GlobalRelation)
        targetRelation.ref
    else if (targetRelation instanceof LocalRelation)
        targetRelation.path.followTheDots
    else null // happens when dot path is nonsense
}


def GlobalRelation followTheDots(LocalRelation exp) {
    var targetRelation = if(exp.tail === null || exp.tail.empty) exp.head else exp.tail.last;
    return if (targetRelation instanceof GlobalRelation)
        targetRelation
    else if (targetRelation instanceof LocalRelation)
        targetRelation.followTheDots
    else null // happens when dot path is nonsense
}
```

While we cannot "touch" `tail` in the scope provider, the "magic ingredient" `{LocalRelation.curr=current}` allows the iterative scope provider full access to the *previously* fully resolved and well-defined reference via `curr`. Post scoping, the full resolved and well-defined trail is available via `head` and `tail`.

[... Edited because original was wrong! ...]